# parse api remove 'you already authorized this app' after user authorized the app

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, user-permissions, parse-platform

Im using parse.com login controller to log users into facebook.

if user authorized the app before he gets  'you already authorized this app' from facebook.

anyone know how it can be solved ?

the code Im using:

```
PFLogInViewController *logInController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
logInController.delegate = self;
logInController.fields =  PFLogInFieldsFacebook ;
logInController.facebookPermissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",logInController.facebookPermissions);
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:logInController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why? If they already authorized it, you shouldn't need or care if they authorize again. When you get back from FB, they will be authorized

Comment: when you call logInController.facebookPermissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
facebook returns the screen if the user already authorized. I want a way to save the hassle to the user authorizing it again.

Comment: you should be storing the session so that you don't have to go to Facebook every time the user uses the app

Comment: yes, but i am using parse api, so this is the question, how ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are showing the view unnecessarily. Try only presenting the PFLogInViewController if [PFUser currentUser] returns nil.

Comment: I do that already, Thats not solving the problem, the problem is *when* I present the login view controller it automatically use the facebookPermissions which generates the message. what I need is away to cause PFLogInViewController not to send the permissions again as the user already authorized the app. right now it seems the only way to do it is not using parse to manage the login and do it using the facebook sdk itself

Comment: So if you already _have_ a logged in user, why are you trying to display the PFLogInViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas is right.  In addition, your navigationController should not be presenting the modal.  *self* should be.

Comment: see my comment above , the problem is not when to call , the problem is how to make the logincontroller not to use the permissions